# How UIActivityController is presented?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am trying to present a custom size `UIViewController` on top of `UITableViewController` without dismissing the `UITableViewController` but I could not. All I could do was to add the view of the `UIViewController` as subview.

The `UIActivityController` seems to be working differently when it is presented. The presenting view controller is not set to nil.

How can I present a custom size `UIViewController` -as the `UIActivityController`-  without dismissing the presenting view controller ?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can do:

```
ActivityViewController *activity = [[ActivityViewController alloc]init];
[self addChildViewController:activity];
[self.view addSubview:activity.view];
```

Here, ActivityViewController is your custom `UIViewController` and inside its `viewDidLoad` or so, you can set its frame to the height you like. Or you can have a method which can be used to vary the height according to the number of buttons you have inside that `UIView`

Comment: if am adding it as subview at the end, how adding it as child makes a difference? Thank you

Comment: My app used to crash without adding that line.